# Background image not showing in CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I've tried to put a background image of a tileable galaxy on my website, but all its showing up is just red. I've tried removing the background color but then it just shows white. I've looked around but I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

```
<style>
body {background-color:#800000;background- 
image:url("https://srv4.imgonline.com.ua/result_img/imgonline-com-ua- 
TextureSeamless-6dnmvt65oVOZjthV.png");
background-repeat:repeat;background-position:center center;
background-attachment:scroll;}
</style>
```

Any advice?

Comment: The link of the images is broken. Try downloading your image and embed it locally rather than using it's original url.

Comment: Don't worry it happens all the time ;) You migth want to close your question or delete it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An image you are looking is not available on this below URL

```
https://srv4.imgonline.com.ua/result_img/imgonline-com-ua- 
TextureSeamless-6dnmvt65oVOZjthV.png
```

For example you can try something like this:

```css
html{
    background: url('https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png') no-repeat 0 0 scroll;
    background-color:#0C0C0C;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your image link is broken.

Try using another link, for your syntax is correct in the CSS.

Here is an example image link: https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/thumb_large/1479467/543360034/stock-photo-close-up-of-milky-way-galaxy-with-stars-and-space-dust-in-the-universe-long-exposure-photograph-543360034.jpg

Comment: Why was I downvoted? I clearly answer the question and offered a solution. If the downvoter, or another user, has feedback on how to improve my answer, I would greatly appreciate it.